# Android APP using Arabic Reshaper/KIVY crashes

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, arabic, buildozer

I have been experimenting with KIVY + Arabic text using Reshaper library 
Has anybody succeeded in deploying APK to Android?
I could run the APP on Linux/Pycharm setup Flawlessly, but when I deploy it to Android it Crashes on startup

If I remove import code lines for both Reshaper and BIDI algorithm, it works on Android

Any hint?

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever configured the buildozer.spec file ? If you import libraries or  frameworks that are not built-in, so you need to specify the libraries that you want to use in **buildozer.spec** file.

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy
```

Add the libraries in **requirements** line as shown above.

Comment: I add it to specs file:
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,arabic_reshaper

I get this error :
python  :  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/arabic_reshaper/__version__.py

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and solve it as follows:

1. By adding six and future to the buildozer.spec file requirements

   ```
    requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,six,future,arabic-reshaper,python-bidi
   ```
2. By Copying the font_file "ARIAL.TTF" into :

   ```
   Application_fldr/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/package_name/arm64-v8a/kivymd/fonts/
   ```

where :
Application_fldr is the folder containing the main.py of your application
package_name is the same as in the buildozer.spec file